# I am trying to convert string into integer, but I cannot print the result out

Tags: java, string

I am trying to convert string into integers but when I try to print the result I cannnot get the right output.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str ="-123456";
        int i = atoi(str);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static int atoi(String str){
        if (str == null || str.length() < 1)
            return 0;
        str = str.trim();
        char flag = '+';

        int i = 0;
        if (str.charAt(0) == '-'){
            flag = '-';
            i++;
        } else if (str.charAt(0) == '+'){
            i++;
        }

        double result = 0;
        while (str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9'){
            result = result * 10 + (str.charAt(i)-'0');
            i++;
        }

        if (flag == '-'){
            result = -result;
        }

        if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        if (result < Integer.MIN_VALUE){
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        return (int) result;
    }
}
```

[This is the result after I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNLrb.png)

Comment: Note that unless this is an exercise, you might as well use `Integer.parseInt(String str)` instead of implementing your own `atoi`.

Comment: I guess using `Integer.parseInt()` is not an answer? Concerning your code, the error is `while (str.length() > 1` because str does not change so this condition is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this: Note i < str.length() instead of str.length() > 1

Explanation: Your error was "index out of range" meaning you're trying to access a character that isn't in the range of the length of the straight and ins this case str.charAt(7), which doesn't exist, so you have to limit i to being less than length of the string.

```
while (i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9'){
        result = result * 10 + (str.charAt(i)-'0');
        i++;
}
```

Comment: An explanation as to why this works would be more beneficial. For example letting OP know that str.length() will never change with the current code.